# User-defined data type issue in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server

I have created a not nullable user defined data type using the below script

```
CREATE TYPE ssn
FROM varchar(11) NOT NULL ;
```

But the user-defined data type is allowing `NULL` value. I am using SQL Server 2014 Developer edition. Please let me know if I am missing something.

Proof of concept:

```
DECLARE @a ssn = NULL; 
SELECT @a
```

Answer (score 3):

The `NOT NULL` constraint only applies to values when the type is used as a data type for a column in a table, not for variables. The following would not work:

```
CREATE TYPE ssn
FROM varchar(11) NOT NULL;
create table foo (id integer primary key, foo_ssn ssn);

insert into foo values (1, null);
```

The insert results in

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'foo_ssn',

Comment: But how to make use the user defined data type for variables?

Comment: I don't think you can do it

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is due to [`ANSI_WARNINGS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190368.aspx).

> When set to `ON`, the divide-by-zero and arithmetic overflow errors
>   cause the statement to be rolled back and an error message is
>   generated

But in case of `SET/SELECT`,

> ANSI_WARNINGS is not honored when passing parameters in a stored
>   procedure, user-defined function, or when declaring and setting
>   variables in a batch statement.

For example, if a variable is defined as `char(3)`, and then set to a value larger than three characters, the data is truncated to the defined size and the INSERT or UPDATE statement succeeds.

```
DECLARE @var char(3)
SET @var = 'ABCDEF'
SELECT @var --ABC
```

The above query works even though we are inserting more than 3 character's

When you try to do the same thing in Table

```
CREATE table test(colu CHAR(3))
INSERT INTO test VALUES('ABCDEF')
```

Will fail, saying

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 9 String or binary data would be
>   truncated.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on what @a_horse_with_no_name was [saying](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35113846/577765) with regards to `NOT NULL` working only on columns and not variables:

A variable is of a particular datatype (i.e. type and, when applicable, max size or precision/scale), but will not take on any other properties or constraints, such as:

- NOT NULL
- IDENTITY
- Collation
- DEFAULT CONSTRAINT
- ROWGUIDCOL
- SPARSE

Even though you are able to declare a variable as the User-Defined Data Type (UDDT) that you created (which includes NOT NULL as part of its definition), you could not declare a variable using `NOT NULL`:

```sql
DECLARE @Bob INT NOT NULL;
```

Returns:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near 'NOT'.